# BindingContext in MasterDetailPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So, I have trouble binding data to my MasterDetailView. I'm getting no errors, and my code seems to be correct, based on sources that I have found online. However, nothing populates my MasterDetailView..

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Menu" BackgroundColor="#9BD2AD" x:Name="test">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="MENU" TextColor="#106073" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="0,20,0,0" FontSize="Large"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding listOfItems}" x:Name="navigationDrawerList" RowHeight="55" SeparatorVisibility="None"> <!--ItemSelected="NavigationDrawerList_ItemSelected"-->
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell> 
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Padding="20,10,0,0">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="#106073" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                <BoxView WidthRequest="2" HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Beige"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Cs

```
private List<MasterPageItem> listOfItems = new List<MasterPageItem>();
MasterPageItem pages = new MasterPageItem();
public SlideMenu()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    test.BindingContext = getPages();
}

public List<MasterPageItem> getPages()
{
    listOfItems.Add(new MasterPageItem("TEST1", typeof(Test1)));
    listOfItems.Add(new MasterPageItem("TEST2", typeof(Test2)));
    return listOfItems;
}
```

MasterPageItem class

```
public class MasterPageItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Type TargetType { get; set; }

    public MasterPageItem()
    {
    }
    public MasterPageItem(string Title, Type TargetType)
    {
        this.Title = Title;
        this.TargetType = TargetType;
    }
}
```

Comment: `"{Binding listOfItems}"` will not work, because `listOfItems` is not a public property of your `BindingContext.`. Try `"{Binding .}"` instead.

Comment: Christ, well spotted. You are correct!